# Cookies - Not deleting

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I have a login page which creates three cookies when logged in correctly, using this code:

```
setcookie('loginAuthorised', 'loginAuthorised', time()+3600, '/');

setcookie('accessLevel', $accessLevel, time()+3600, '/');

setcookie('userID', $userID, time()+3600, '/');
```

When the user logs out, the cookies are supposed to be deleted, using this code:

```
setcookie("loginAuthorised", "", time()-7200);

setcookie("accessLevel", "", time()-7200);

setcookie("userID", "", time()-7200);
```

For some reason, my cookies are not being deleted. They are collecting the values correctly, and they work for keeping the user logged in through pages, but when it comes to the logout part, they are not deleted.

The logout button code is as follows:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?status=logout">

    <span style="color: maroon;">Logout</span>

</a>';
```

The code which checks the 'status' is as follows:

```
$status = $_GET['status'];

if (isset($status) AND ($status == "logout")) {

    // Cookie deletion code

}
```

All help will be appreciated :)

Comment: You need the `/` as the last param in setcookie like you have when creating them

Comment: Ah, yes. I have used cookies before and successfully deleted them. It's always the small things that mess up your code. Thanks @fire!

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['remember_user'])) {
            unset($_COOKIE['Hello']);
            unset($_COOKIE['HelloTest1']);
            setcookie('Hello', null, -1, '/');
            setcookie('HelloTest1', null, -1, '/');
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```